# Move an image to a specific location

Tags: python

How to make it so the inserted image moves to a specific location and ends the program?

I tried using a counter loop but I still can't figure it out.

```
mr_krabs2.draw(win3)

key = win3.getKey()
counter = 0
while True:
    counter +=1 
    if key == "w":
        mr_krabs2.move(0,-10)
        counter = count - 1
        time.sleep(0.1)
    if key == "s":
        mr_krabs2.move(0,10)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    if key == "a":
        mr_krabs2.move(-10,0)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    if key == "d":
        mr_krabs2.move(10,0)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        
    for count in range (10):
        print("a")
        time.sleep(10)
        win3.close
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop and are never **checking** the counter... Beyond that, `quit()` will stop the program. Also, `win3.close()` is a proper function call

Comment: Yes I don't know the logic of making it count every key I might even need a x and y variable instead of a counter.

Comment: All I'm saying is that you've stated a problem without a clear goal. For example _where_ do you want to move the image to? What was the specific purpose of trying to use the counter? And why do you need to print 10 `a` at the end if that has nothing to do with moving images?

Comment: If you want to move to a specific `x,y` location, and assuming you start at `(0,0)`, then you can just call `.move(x, y)`. There is no need for checking key presses, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my question.

```
# Variables for x and y to have a precise location. 
x = 0.0
y = 0.0

while True:
    key = win3.getKey()

# Key Movement.
    if key == "w":
        mr_krabs2.move(0,-10)
        y = y + 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")
    if key == "s":
        mr_krabs2.move(0,10)
        y = y - 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")
    if key == "a":
        mr_krabs2.move(-10,0)
        x = x + 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")
    if key == "d":
        mr_krabs2.move(10,0)
        x = x - 10
        print("\nx =",x,"y =",y,"\n")
        
# Making a hitbox
    if (x < (59) and
        x > (52) and
        y < (4) and
        y > (-6)):
        time.sleep(5)
        win3.close()
        break
```